# Evaluate logical expression wrong SAS

Tags: sas

I'm triying to run the next Macro, and I have hoped the expression "&minimum_age le &age le &maximum_age" take a false value, so output at log should be: "Under the required age", but evaluation is take value true. I really do not understand it.

```
%let date_of_birth = '11may2008'd;
%let minimum_age = 18;
%let maximum_age = 72;
%let age = %sysfunc(int(%sysfunc(yrdif(&date_of_birth,%sysfunc(today()),'AGE'))));
%put &= &age;

%Macro test;
%if not(&minimum_age le &age le &maximum_age) %then %put Under the required age;
%Mend;
%test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation :

`&minimum_age le &age` is evaluated to "0"

then

`0 le &maximum_age` is evaluated to 1

so `not(1)` = 0

and finally , `%put Under the required age` is not executed

Change to :

```
%let date_of_birth = '11may2008'd;
%let minimum_age = 18;
%let maximum_age = 72;
%let age = %sysfunc(int(%sysfunc(yrdif(&date_of_birth,%sysfunc(today()),'AGE'))));
%put &= &age;

%Macro test;
%put %eval(&minimum_age ge &age);
%put %eval(&age ge &maximum_age);
%if &minimum_age ge &age or &age ge &maximum_age %then %put Under or up to the required age;
%Mend;
%test;
```